# React.cloneElement: distinguish element from its clone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, clone-element

After

```
const element = <MyComp />
const cloned = React.cloneElement(element, someProps)
```

both an element and its clone are rendered.
(The original element is rendered into a portal.)

Now I need to attach a ref to `cloned` but not `element`.

I believe I can achieve this by setting custom DOM props, e.g.:

```
const cloned = React.cloneElement(element, { ...someProps, 'data-cloned': true })
```

and discovering the prop in a callback ref on `MyComp`:

```
const element = <MyComp ref={el => if (el.dataset.cloned) { myRef.current = el }}
```

but it feels like I might be missing a better way of doing this than setting and reading from data attributes?

*(Update: and it seems it doesn't work because with this mechanism I never know which instance should reset the ref to null)*

Comment: It is possible to pass ref when cloning the element. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17407

Comment: yeah I don't know how to build this in my situation but definitely that would be the way to go.